# untangle server at work place privacy

Tags: network, privacy, webserver

When I am browsing in an environment where [Untangle](https://www.untangle.com/) server is installed, can the network admin track everything I do? for example:

- Skype chat messages
- Personal emails (Gmail, Yahoo)

Comment: The general answer to these types of questions is: your employer could track almost everything you do. They probably don't, as it requires effort, but unless you can guarantee the integrity of your device, and use end to end encryption then don't rely on it being secure.

Comment: +1 to @RoryAlsop. I'm not sure if we've got a canonical "can my employer see what I'm doing at work" question here yet, but my answers to these always include something along the line of "leave your personal stuff at home".

Comment: found this tool which allows to view skype chats, contacts and call logs. http://www.ghacks.net/2014/04/18/skypefreak-dumps-contact-call-message-profile-information-skype/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Untangle has the capability of intercepting HTTPS using a man in the middle proxy (https://www.untangle.com/store/https-inspector.html). If this is enabled, the HTTPS inspector can see all HTTPS traffic. This however requires that all desktop client install a root certificate issued by the Untangle device.

Comment: ...or that users click through an "Untrusted Certificate" warning in their browser. Chat clients and other applications may not be so tolerant, but most web browsers will allow users to optionally proceed despite problems with SSL certificates - and many users are happy to click through anything that stands between them and [insert web application of choice].

Comment: All it takes is for a root ca to be installed on a system which is controlled by a it department and not a employee , really won't be that much effort for a standard desktop image.

Answer (score 2):

I think the traceability of your connections will be recorded on the log file of untangle server but not the content of your conversations .

Answer (score 1):

A local certificate authority (CA) must be setup by an administrator. The administrator tells your browser that this CA is trustworthy. The proxy server uses this CA to sign the forged certificates at which point the HTTPS proxy (in this case, the Untangle server) would now have the ability to decrypt the HTTPS traffic.

Can the administrator track what you're doing? If the administrator is monitoring the traffic logs, the administrator would be able to identify the use of Skype/Gmail/Yahoo/etc on the network.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for the admin to access the underlying Untangle system via ssh or the local console and use any commonly available Linux tool to see the raw packets.  Untangle discourages it as automatic updates may remove your tools, or the tools may break the system.

Comment: But Untangle doesn't have this option as part of it's UI, right? Any machine could also do the same thing, so that fact that it's on the Untangle box is secondary.

Comment: True. All you would need is the actual packet capture. You can use Wireshark to analyze the PCAP.